# java csvreader reads special character incorrectly

Tags: java, csv

I'm using open csv parser.My csv file contains a special character like this "‼".

I read this character frm a csv file and read it into another csv file using java.

When I open the output csv file it contains ? instead of the character ‼

I specified UTF-8 as an argument when reading and writing the file.

Here is my code:

```
    Map<String, String> feedValues = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream(csvFilename)));
    List content = csvReader.readAll();
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(..);
    List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    for (Object object : content) {
        row = (String[]) object;
        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            row[i] = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(row[i]);
            row[i] = row[i].replace("\n", " ");
        }
        data.add(row);
    }
    writer.writeAll(data);
```

Comment: Posting your code will help us to help you.

Comment: Map<String, String> feedValues = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(csvFilename)));
List content = csvReader.readAll();
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(..);
 List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for (Object object : content) {
    row = (String[]) object;
   for(int i = 0 ; i < row.length; i ++){
    row[i] = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(row[i]); 
    row[i] = row[i].replace("\n", " ");
   }
   data.add(row);
}  writer.writeAll(data);

Comment: this is the text I've in the input csv file. "this is a test for special char  ‼"